# When I launch sdkmanager I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema exception

Tags: android, macos, react-native, android-sdk-manager, macos-big-sur

I upgrade macOS to BigSur, and then I cannot launch sdkmanager.

when I run

```sh
$ANDROID_SDK/tools/sdkmanager
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

My java environment is Java8

```sh
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

```sh
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    14.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 14.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.152.16 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_152 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
```